# How to use Debian package cl-mssql?

Tags: sql-server, linux, debian

I found a debian package called cl-mssql. Its description is "Common Lisp interface to MS SQL Server". I installed the package on Debian Stretch with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cl-mssql
```

The install worked as expected. However, there is no man page and I can't find anywhere online how to use this package. I am wanting to connect and query a SQL Server database. How do you use this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is a library meant to be used with implementations of the Common Lisp programming language. It is not a program with an user interface. Therefore, to use the package you need to write a Common Lisp program using the library, which I don't think is what you want.

Comment: I believe you are right, not what I am looking for. Thanks!